# Not tracking usage in applicationinsight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a webapps on which I am using applciationinsight with web sdk, but I am not able to track usage in azure portal , it was tracking before I undo the code but after undo ,again I installed application insights for my application but now it's not tracking any usage.even though telemetry key is same and not getting error, please assist me on it 
Thanks

Comment: By "Usage" do you mean page views?  if you also want to collect page views, then you also need to inject javascript into the code that generates your pages (_layout.cshtml or site.master, etc)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-javascript/  .  simply re-adding the AI Sdks packages wouldn't add any of that stuff if you removed it.

Comment: we'll need lots more info:  what sdks are you using? what versions? how are you configuring them? do you have a resource configured/ikey set?  are you seing debug output from those sdks when you debug your app? are you seing outbound traffic to dc.services.visualstudio.com for your telemetry?  is that going to the ikey you expect? are any of those outbound requests failing?, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have updated your applicationInsights.config file with the appropriate key or else Application Insights will be disabled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have application config , i am using webconfig for it, inside web config i defined my key and in application_strat() method i am using it.

Comment: You should reinstall the package as the applicationInsights.config is necessary as far as I know for tracking.  That file appears anytime I add the ApplicationInsights from NuGet to a project.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config/

Comment: I did already and I have 2 solution one for web and one for api , and for web without application-insights is working but in api I am facing the issue